# How do I speed up my Umbraco 4 Website?

Tags: iis, umbraco, umbraco4

I am new to umbraco, I have a website made in Umbraco version 4.11.10 & it some times really slows down. And I need the ways to speedup my website. It uses the uCommerce package also.

I am aware of AppWarmUp feature of IIS, also I need to know wheater upgreading my website to Umbraco Version 7.6 can help me in this regard?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit broad for a question but I can offer you a couple of tips that usually speed up Umbraco.

1. Use macro caching, this allows you to avoid running macros that are basically static - like your header/footer etc - this can speed things up enormously

[image]

2. Use the querystring parameter ?umbdebugshowtrace=true and have a look at which parts of your page are taking too long - and focus on them.

Obviously #2 could throw up anything!

Incidentally there is no upgrade path from v4 to v7 - the Umbraco owner Niels Hartvig has often discussed the 'Upgrade Myth' (http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2011/11/14/the-upgrade-myth.aspx)